# cosine similarity optimized implementation

Tags: python, python-2.7, optimization, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to understand this optimized code to find cosine similarity between users matrix.

```
def fast_similarity(ratings,epsilon=1e-9):
    # epsilon -> small number for handling dived-by-zero errors
    sim = ratings.T.dot(ratings) + epsilon
    norms = np.array([np.sqrt(np.diagonal(sim))])
    return (sim / norms / norms.T)
```

If ratings =

```
           items           
     u  [
     s    [1,2,3]
     e    [4,5,6]
     r    [7,8,9] 
     s  ]
```

nomrs will be equal to = [1^2 + 5^2 + 9^2]

but why we are writing sim/norms/norms.T to calculate cosine similarity?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I posted this question earlier on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/159231/cosine-similarity-optimization and got a comment that its not right place. I hope this is the right place for such questions

Comment: For details: Source Code has been taken from http://blog.ethanrosenthal.com/2015/11/02/intro-to-collaborative-filtering/ .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Going through the code we have that:

[image: first]

And this means that, one the diagonal of the `sim` matrix we have the result of the multiplication of each column.

You can give it a try if you want using a simple matrix:

[image: second]

And you can easily check that this [gram matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/874429/matrix-transpose-times-itself) (that's how this matrix product is named) has this property.

Now the code defines `norms` that is nothing but an array taking the diagonal of our `gram matrix` and apply a sqrt on each element of it.

This will give us an array containing the norm value for each column:

[image: third]

So basically the `norms` vector contains the norm value of each column of the `result` matrix.

Once we have all those data we can evaluate the cosine similarity between those users, so we know that cosine similarity is evaluated like:

[image: forth]

Note that :
[image: fifth]

So we have that our similarity is going to be:

[image: six]

So we just have to substitute the terms with our code variable to get:

[image: seven]

And this explain why you have this line of code:

```
return sim / norms / norms.T
```

**EDIT:**
Since it seems that I was not clear, every time I am talking about matrix multiplication in this answer I am reffering to the `DOT PRODUCT` of two matrices.

> This actually means that when it's written A*B we actually develop and
>   solve as A.T * B

Comment: You meant `A * B = transpose(A) * A`?

Comment: we are talking about `dot product`

Comment: Then it would be better, if you explicitly specify.

Comment: how you are substituting norms = A.T since norms in above example = [66,93,126] and A.T is 3x3 matrix as shown above

Comment: where did you read norms = A.T? I wrote: `the code defines norms that is nothing but an array taking the diagonal of our gram matrix and apply a sqrt on each element of it.`

Comment: while substituting. I meant norms = ||A.T||

Comment: As I worte the norm vector has an entry for each column of the matrix, this means that norm = ||A.T|| makes sense. This means that norm is a nx1 array instead A is an nxn matrix

Comment: The norm vector is supposed to contain a normalized value for each row of our target matraix that is A. Since our norms array contains one normalized value for each `column` of A we can state that this is exactly ||A.T|| (note that if we transpose A we have that now norm is containing all the normalized values of the `rows` of A.T).

Comment: may be I lack some basic concept of matrix and that's why its getting hard to understand the above line. if you can show by taking some example, it will be quite ehlp[ful

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139347/discussion-between-rakwaht-and-manish-kumar).